# In Scala - How to get the day of the week?

Tags: scala

Suppose my date format is 21/05/2017 then the output will be SUN.

How can I get the day given a date?

Answer (score 5):

```
    import java.time.LocalDate
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

    val df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")
    val dayOfWeek = LocalDate.parse("21/05/2017",df).getDayOfWeek
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) as illustrated below:

```
import java.util.Calendar
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

val now = Calendar.getInstance.getTime

val date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
date.format(now)
res1: String = 2017-05-20

val dowInt = new SimpleDateFormat("u")
dowInt.format(now)
res2: String = 6

val dowText = new SimpleDateFormat("E")
dowText.format(now)
res3: String = Sat
```

[UPDATE]

As per comments below, please note that `SimpleDateFormat` isn't thread-safe.

Comment: @Zernike, you're right, even though thread-safety wasn't a requirement in the OP, I suppose it's time to let go of the old API that many of us get so used to.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `nscala-time` which is a Scala wrapper for Java's `joda-time` which is a datetime library with a ton of functionality.

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._

val someDate =(newDateTime).withYear(2017)
                           .withMonthOfYear(5)
                           .withDayOfMonth(21)

someDate.getDayOfWeek

res7: Int = 7
```

Now you need to know the mapping between integer days of the week and names. Here, 7 corresponds to Sunday.