# Spark scala: obtaining weekday from utcstamp (function works for specific date, not for entire column)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, datetime, apache-spark-sql, weekday

I have a scala / spark dataframe, with one column named "utcstamp" with values of the following format: `2018-12-12 21:15:00`

I want to obtain a new column with the week day, and inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089758/in-scala-how-to-get-the-day-of-the-week) question in the forum, used the following code:

```
import java.util.Calendar
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

val dowText = new SimpleDateFormat("E")
df = df.withColumn("weekday" , dowText.format(df.select(col("utcstamp"))))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
<console>:58: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

When I try this applied to a specific date (like in the link provided) it works, I just can't apply it to the whole column.

Can anyone help me with this? If you have an alternative way of converting an utc column into weekday that'll also do for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dayofweek` function of Spark SQL, which gives you a number from 1-7, for Sunday to Saturday:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("weekday", dayofweek(col("utcstamp").cast("timestamp")))
```

Or if you want words (Sun-Sat) instead,

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("weekday", date_format(col("utcstamp").cast("timestamp"), "EEE"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the day of week with date format as `"E"` or `EEEE` (eg. for Sun and Sunday)

```
df.withColumn("weekday", date_format(to_timestamp($"utcstamp"), "E"))
```

If you want day of week as numeric value use `dayofweek` function which is availabe from `spark 2.3+`